# Microfrontend Fixing Conflicting styles issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am having a Microfrontend application, which internally uses Material UI dependency (at the Host and Child MFE).

I am running into a CSS conflict issue where in the problem occurs if the order of loading styles are as below;

```
<!-- Default Material UI styles -->
<style data-jss data-meta="MuiButtonBase">/* ... */</style> 
<!-- Your Button Material UI styles -->
<style data-jss data-meta="MuiButtonBase">/* ... */</style>
<!-- THE PROBLEMATIC STYLES: Default Material UI styles, AGAIN -->
<style data-jss data-meta="MuiButtonBase">/* ... */</style>
```

I am trying to understand the solution provided at this page
https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/issues/1071
The solution I am referring on this page is where it is using the StylesProvider (where it says "*The solution to me was to isolate the classNames per micro-frontend, so no micro-frontend can inject jss styles that can override the others.*").

However I am quite confused as to how/where to this StylesProvider to?
**Specifically my question is if this StylesProvider is to be applied only at the Host or even at the Child MFE.**

My setup is something as below;

In my Host App.js, I have

```
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {HashRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div>HOST APP: <br /></div>
        <a href="/my-inq">Link to child app</a>
        <Route exact path="/myinq-ui">
          <MyInqWrapper  />
        </Route>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In MyInqWrapper.jsx, I have

```
import React from 'react';
import { Spinner } from 'reactstrap';

// @ts-ignore
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
const MyInq = React.lazy(() => import('myInqMfe/MyInq'))

const MyInqWrapper = ()=>{
  return(
    <div>
      <React.Suspense  fallback={<Spinner/>}>
        <MyInq />
      </React.Suspense>
    </div>
  )
};

export default MyInqWrapper;
```

Also, my Child App.js is as below;

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import MyInq from "./my-inq/MyInq";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Router>
                <Route exact path="/search">
                  <Search url={user} />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/myinq-ui">
                  <MyInq />
                </Route>
              </Router>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to add a prefix selector to your child MFE (`my-unique-child-prefix`).

By using MUI experimental API [`ClassName generator`](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/classname-generator/) that allows you to define the shape of the css selectors (since v5.0.5),

```js
// Child app class name setup
// create a new file called `MuiClassNameSetup.js` at the root or src folder.
import { unstable_ClassNameGenerator as ClassNameGenerator } from '@mui/material/className';

ClassNameGenerator.configure(
  // Do something with the componentName
  (componentName) => `my-unique-child-prefix-${componentName}`,
);
```